# Change AppBarLayout theme programmatically?

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-appbarlayout

I have an AppBarLayout defined as such

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

However, sometimes I change the theme for the application and I also want to change it, and its children's. I have been partially successful by doing this:

```
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar_layout);
    appBarLayout.getContext().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dark_AppBarOverlay);
    appBarLayout.invalidate();
```

However, the TextView for the title is not getting the theme settings.

How can I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to use a ViewStub (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) that held two versions of my AppBarLayout: Light and Dark.

Then in `onCreate` I checked which theme was being loaded and replaced the ViewStub with the correct `R.layout`. I don't know why this is so difficult, or why you can't change the 'theme' for sub-views when you change the theme for the entire Activity, it's really perplexing.

In any case, this was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for Context.setTheme()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme(int)):

> Set the base theme for this context. Note that this should be called
>   before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before
>   calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).

The bottom line is that setting the theme on a `Context` affects views that are created later. This means you'll have to rebuild your layout after `setTheme()`.

Comment: True, but I'm setting it on AppBarLayout, not the entire app. I used getContext() because it seems the context for the AppBarLayout isn't the same as the whole. If I need to rebuild just part of it (I can'get it before the view builds I assume), how can I do that

Comment: You'll have to rebuild the AppBarLayout at the very least. You can use a [ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) on the base context to re-inflate the views with another theme. That way your base context isn't affected.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to set android:theme on an AppBarLayout? This doesn't make any sense, why have themes on widgets if you can't change them?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Views read theme attributes in their constructors and style themselves accordingly. This affects children all the way down the view hierarchy. Trying to set the theme after creation is like trying to unscramble an egg.

Comment: That's unfortunate, and a rather terrible design decision IMO. I can change the theme for the app, but not a view? =\